# Android Studio tools to show CPU registers and instructions

Tags: android-studio, cpu-registers, disassembly

In Eclipse with CDT we have *Window->Show View->Registers* and *Window->Show View->Disassembly* windows allowing to watch CPU instructions flow and CPU registers values. I used to use those to debug CPU and NEON code. I am able to debug native code in Eclipse, but I can't see such functionality in Android Studio (1.5.1)

Is there any plug-in or functionality available to debug CPU instruction level code under Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

When your breakpoint is hit, simply click on the LLDB window, and enter `disassemble` to see the CPU instructions:
[image: Android Studio disassembly]

To see the registers, enter `register read`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Studio's LLDB integrated CLI (command line interface) to do so (please refer to this [mapping](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html) between GDB and LLVM commands)

Unfortunately I haven't found any GUI that does the same as CDT does.